# Handlebars: How to write an if conditional

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am very new to Handlebars ....

I have a variable in JavaScript that hold string value ....

```
var answer = 'Yes';
```

This is what I want to in my Handlebar template (pseudocode) ...

```
{{#if answer == 'Yes'}}
  <div>You are in</div>
{{else}}
    <div>You are out</div>
{{/if}}
```

How do I do something like this ? I have seen the manuals [here](https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) but they are not very helpful.

Also, there is a solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712361/logic-in-handlebars-if-else-statement) without any kind of explanation at all. Nothing is clear in this solution. Like

1. How the 'registerHelper function' is called ?
2. What values are passed to 'string1' and 'string2' ?
3. How to pass values to string1 and string2 ?

As I said, at the start that I am a beginner with Handlebars and I am not interested in simply copy and pasting without understanding on how it all works.

It would be great if someone can please explain on how to do such comparisons.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "without any explanation at all" which part of the linked answer is not clear? Please ask more specific question.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Nothing is clear. How the 'registerHelper function' is called ? What values are passed to string1 and string2 ? How to pass values to string1 and string2 ?

Comment: Read the "Getting started" section from https://handlebarsjs.com/. You first have to "compile" the template. In your trivial case, you don't need to register helper functions.

Comment: "How the 'registerHelper function' is called" you need to call it once you configure handlebars. "What values are passed to string1 and string2 ?" the values you want to check for equality. "How to pass values to string1 and string2 ?"  `{{#equals value1 value2}} truthy {{else}} falsy {{/equals}}`

Comment: Thanks @YuryTarabanko Can you please answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715374/handlebar-conditional-not-working) related question ?