# Conditionally rendering markup in HTML email and sending it using AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, html-email, amazon-ses

We are trying to add conditional logic to an HTML email template that is then sent using AWS SES services. We have managed to find a way of doing so using handlebar helpers from handlebars.js, but when using these, AWS refuses to send our email.

We followed examples like these (look at the "if_eq" section):[enter link description here](https://code-maven.com/handlebars-conditionals)
https://code-maven.com/handlebars-conditionals

I have discussed exactly what we tried in more detail in this post
[Implementing handlebar helpers on AWS SES for conditional rendering of markup in an HTML emailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71263091/implementing-handlebar-helpers-on-aws-ses-for-conditional-rendering-of-markup-in)

Since this is not seeming to run, we are looking for another option to conditionally render markup in an HTML email that would be allowed on AWS SES. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most e-mail clients don't allow JavaScript for security reasons. So you are effectively limited to the support SES gives you. The good news is that SES does support conditionals in templates: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-personalized-email-advanced.html#send-personalized-email-advanced-conditional, so all is not lost.